# How to transfer FetchedResults data to an array of object in SWIFTUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list of data from CoreData using fetch results. And I wanted to put that coredata data to a list of array so that I can save the checkbox state in memory not in the database.

Example:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: ParticipantEntity.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ParticipantEntity.first_name, ascending: true)]
) var participantItems:FetchedResults<ParticipantEntity>

**// is there a way to transfer participantItems to a simple list of object?like:
var newItems : participantItems **

var body: some View {

   List {
                ForEach(self.participantItems) { participant in
                    HStack{
                        AsyncImage(
                            url: URL(string: url+(participant.profile_picture ?? "")),
                            content: { image in
                                image.resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 45, maxHeight: 45)
                                    .cornerRadius(5)
                            },
                            placeholder: {
                                Image("no_profile_pic")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 45, maxHeight: 45)
                            }
                        )
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            let fname = participant.first_name ?? ""
                            let lname = participant.last_name ?? ""
                            let name = fname + " " + lname
                            Text(name)
                            Text(participant.group_name ?? "No Group Name")
                        }.padding(.leading, 5.0)
                      
                        Spacer()
                        **Image(systemName: participant.isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                participant.isChecked.toggle()
                            }**
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())

}

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ParticipantEntity.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ParticipantEntity.first_name, ascending: true)]
) var participantItems:FetchedResults<ParticipantEntity>

var newItems = newItems[participantItems]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy the values to a separate array. Have a @State property to hold the selected items:

```swift
@State private var selectedParticipants = Set<Participant>()
```

Then a couple of functions on your view to get and set selection:

```swift
private func isSelected(_ participant: Participant) -> Bool {
    selectedParticipants.contains(participant)
}

private func toggleSelection(of participant: Participant) {
    if isSelected(participant) {
        selectedParticipants.remove(participant)
    } else {
        selectedParticipants.insert(participant)
    }
}
```

So your checkbox would then be:

```swift
Image(systemName: isSelected(participant) ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
.onTapGesture {
    toggleSelection(of: participant)
}
```

Comment: isSelected(participant) : participant is the entity items, the problem here is I don't one to save the checkbox state in the database. I just want to save it on a model for me to get all participants that selected.

Comment: This answer doesn't save the checkbox state in the database. The selected participants are held in that state variable, in memory.